# How to retrieve data solely by foreign key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

The mission: Visualize the patients that were treated by surgeons.

Table: **patients**

- id_patient
- name
- last_name

Table: **doctors**

- id_doctor
- name
- last_name
- speciality ("surgeon" is one of the possibilities)

Table: **visits**

- id_visit
- id_patient_fk (*foreign key*)
- id_doctor_fk (*foreign key*)

With the `id_doctor_fk` pointing to `id_doctor`, I have to see if that doctor is a surgeon, right? Is this possible? I gave up, so I ask.

Comment: Yes, that's what you use a `JOIN` for

Comment: I have been trying to formulate a JOIN that would do that but I can't come up with the solution!

Comment: If you tried something, then please add all your attempts to the question by editing it

Comment: They were a lot, besides if they are wrong there is no point.

Comment: Personally I would drive this from doctor rather than patient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want patients who have seen a surgeon, you can use `exists`:

```
select p.*
from patients p
where exists (select 1
              from visits v join
                   doctors d
                   on d.id_doctor = v.id_doctor_pk
              where v.id_patient_fk = p.id_patient and
                    d.specialty = 'surgeon'
             );
```

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand why v.id_patient_fk = p.id_patient is needed, if I erase it the query won't do what it's desired (it adds all the patients), so it is needed, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @Zeleska . . . The `exists` clause is a *correlated subquery*.  You can think of it as running for each row of the outer query, setting each run to the `p.id_patient` in each row.  That is *conceptually* correct but the SQL optimizer may find a more efficient way of returning the same result.

Answer (score 1):

i created an example for your question . i hope this is help you:

```
CREATE TABLE #patients2 (
  id_patient int,
  [name] VARCHAR(100),
  last_name VARCHAR(100)
);
CREATE TABLE #doctors2 (
  id_doctor int,
  [name] VARCHAR(100),
  last_name VARCHAR(100),
  speciality VARCHAR(100),
);
CREATE TABLE #dvisits2 (
  id_visit int,
  id_patient_fk  int,
  id_doctor_fk  int
);
  --drop table #table1

INSERT INTO #patients2
  (id_patient, [name], last_name)
VALUES
  (1,'patient1','last_name1'),
  (2,'patient2','last_name2'),
  (3,'patient3','last_name3'),
  (4,'patient4','last_name4'),
  (5,'patient5','last_name5'),
  (6,'patient6','last_name6'),
  (7,'patient7','last_name7'),
  (8,'patient8','last_name8');


  INSERT INTO #doctors2
  (id_doctor, [name], last_name, speciality )
VALUES
  (1,'doctor1','last_name1','surgeon'),
  (2,'doctor2','last_name2','not surgeon'),
  (3,'doctor3','last_name3','surgeon'),
  (4,'doctor4','last_name4','not  surgeon'),
  (5,'doctor5','last_name5','surgeon'),
  (6,'doctor6','last_name6','surgeon'),
  (7,'doctor7','last_name7','not surgeon'),
  (8,'doctor8','last_name8','surgeon');

    INSERT INTO #dvisits2
  (id_visit, id_doctor_fk,id_patient_fk)
VALUES
  (1,1,1),
  (2,2,2),
  (3,3,3),
  (4,4,4),
  (5,5,5),
  (6,6,6),
  (7,7,7),
  (8,8,8);


  select * from #patients2 p 
  join #dvisits2 dv on p.id_patient = dv.id_patient_fk
  join #doctors2 doc on dv.id_doctor_fk = doc.id_doctor
  where doc.speciality = 'surgeon'
```

result =

```
id_patient  [name]      last_name   id_visit    id_patient_fk   id_doctor_fk    speciality  id_doctor   [name]      last_name
1           patient1    last_name1      1               1           1           surgeon         1       doctor1     last_name1
1           patient1    last_name1      1               1           1           surgeon         1       doctor1     last_name1
3           patient3    last_name3      3               3           3           surgeon         3       doctor3     last_name3
3           patient3    last_name3      3               3           3           surgeon         3       doctor3     last_name3
5           patient5    last_name5      5               5           5           surgeon         5       doctor5     last_name5
6           patient6    last_name6      6               6           6           surgeon         6       doctor6     last_name6
8           patient8    last_name8      8               8           8           surgeon         8       doctor8     last_name8
```

Comment: NOTE - Mysql does not support # tables or [] as identifier qualifiers.

Comment: Your answer is also helpful and easier to understand, thanks!